# Excel VBA End User Selecting a Chart Object

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I would like to generate some code that allows an end user to select one of many charts from a sheet, after which I will do a bunch of manipulation based on that selection.

I am looking for something similar to the Application.Inputbox Type:=8 that allows for an object selection instead of a range selection.

Am I asking to much of humble old VBA??

Comment: Did you try just `Selection`?

Comment: keep on with the "Range" object got from "Application.Inputbox Type:=8" and get its Sheet reference with "Parent" property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot easier to select the chart first, then run code on the selected chart(s), than it is to pause the code and try to select the chart(s) from within the code.

But it can be done.

You need a userform, called `F_ChartChooser` with two buttons, `btnCancel` and `btnContinue`.

The code in the `F_ChartChooser` module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnCancel_Click()
  CancelProcedure
End Sub

Private Sub btnContinue_Click()
  ContinueProcedure
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
  ' so clicking red X doesn't crash
  If CloseMode = 0 Then
    Cancel = True
    CancelProcedure
  End If
End Sub
```

The code in the regular module consists of a main procedure which must get the chart(s) from the user. It has to call the userform modelessly so the user can select charts in the worksheet. This means the code continues running while the form is displayed, so the thing to do is end the sub when the userform is called.

Based on what happens with the userform, the code either continues with `CancelProcedure` or with `ContinueProcedure`. Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim mfrmChartChooser As F_ChartChooser

Sub Main()
  ' code here

  ' need to select chart(s) here
  Application.Goto ActiveCell
  Set mfrmChartChooser = New F_ChartChooser
  mfrmChartChooser.Show vbModeless
End Sub

Sub CancelProcedure()
  Unload mfrmChartChooser
  Set mfrmChartChooser = Nothing
  MsgBox "User canceled.", vbExclamation
End Sub

Sub ContinueProcedure()
  Unload mfrmChartChooser
  Set mfrmChartChooser = Nothing
  If Not ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
    ' do something with active chart

    ' this demo is announcing that it was selected
    MsgBox """" & ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text & """ was selected.", vbExclamation
    ' end of demo code
  ElseIf TypeName(Selection) = "DrawingObjects" Then
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim vCharts As Variant
    Dim nChart As Long
    ReDim vCharts(0 To nChart)
    For Each sh In Selection.ShapeRange
      If sh.HasChart Then
        ' do something here with each chart

        ' this demo is building a list of selected charts
        nChart = nChart + 1
        ReDim Preserve vCharts(0 To nChart)
        vCharts(nChart) = sh.Chart.ChartTitle.Text
        ' end of demo code
      End If
    Next

    ' this demo now is showing the list of selected charts
    If nChart = 0 Then
      MsgBox "No chart selected.", vbExclamation
    Else
      If nChart = 1 Then
        MsgBox """" & vCharts(nChart) & """ was selected.", vbExclamation
      Else
        Dim sPrompt As String
        sPrompt = nChart & " charts selected:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        Dim iChart As Long
        For iChart = 1 To nChart
          sPrompt = sPrompt & """" & vCharts(iChart) & """" & IIf(iChart < nChart, vbNewLine, "")
        Next
        MsgBox sPrompt, vbExclamation
      End If
    End If
    ' end of demo code
  Else
    ' do nothing because no chart was selected

    ' this demo is announcing that nothing was selected
    MsgBox "No chart selected.", vbExclamation
    ' end of demo code
  End If
End Sub
```

The `CancelProcedure` and `ContinueProcedure` routines above have excess code in them just to help with the demo. In real code I would streamline them like this, probably not even bother to notify the user when nothing was selected (they know they canceled, right?), and just process the selected chart(s):

```
Sub CancelProcedure()
  Unload mfrmChartChooser
  Set mfrmChartChooser = Nothing
End Sub

Sub ContinueProcedure()
  Unload mfrmChartChooser
  Set mfrmChartChooser = Nothing
  If Not ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
    ' do something with active chart
    ProcessChart ActiveChart
  ElseIf TypeName(Selection) = "DrawingObjects" Then
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim vCharts As Variant
    Dim nChart As Long
    ReDim vCharts(0 To nChart)
    For Each sh In Selection.ShapeRange
      If sh.HasChart Then
        ' do something here with each chart
        ProcessChart sh.Chart
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Jon  that is exactly what i was looking for.  While thinking this through I also came back to 'selecting first' option